# New column in Excel to determine if given account number has one or both product types

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a three-column data set in Excel: Column A is **Account Number**, Column B is **Product Type**, and Column C is **Current Balance** (see image below).

[image: three-column data set as described]

The table I'm using has +150,000 rows, the image above is for illustrative purpose to simplify what I'm looking at. Multiple rows may have the same **Account Number**, but a different **Product Type** and/or **Current Balance**.

I would like to create a new column for a unique identifier that would label an **Account Number** as having *"All A's"*, *"All B's"*, or *"Both"*. What in Excel (formula, VBA, etc) can be used to achieve this?

Comment: Kris, have you gotten your answer yet? If you have, please mark one of the below as accepted (if it was one of those) or post it here so that others can benefit from it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a helper column in `Column A` and use the following formula starting in `A2`

`=IF(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$9,$B2)=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$9,$B2,$C$2:$C$9,$C2),"All "&$C2&"'s","Both")`

[image]

**EDIT:**

You can also take it one step further and only return the requested answer for the first occurrence of an **Account Number** by using the following formula (again by beginning in `A2`)

`=IF(COUNTIF($B$2:$B2,$B2)>1,"",IF(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$9,$B2)=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$9,$B2,$C$2:$C$9,$C2),"All "&$C2&"'s","Both"))`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe this formula would work (tweak for your ranges):

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$9,"A",$A$2:$A$9,D2)>0,COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$9,"B",$A$2:$A$9,D2)),"Both",IF(COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$9,"A",$A$2:$A$9,D2)>0,"All A's","All B's"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@Kris - Please try the below solution.

I have added a new column by concatenating Account Number and Product Type. Using this column, created an Identifier column with the formula below.

**Identifier column formula:**

```
IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$9,A2)=COUNTIF($D$2:$D$9,D2),"All"&B2,"Both")
```

[image]

Hope this helps.